# What is the use of the te-form of 違って in 違って見えるね?

Tags: て-form

In the phrase:

> 今日はいつもと***違って***見えるね - You look different today.

What is 違って doing here? Why is it being used instead of 違う?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93068/30454